# How to redirect to 404 error page when user enters wrong url php

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, file-not-found

I am building a static Html website. When a user first enters into my website at first he/she is redirected to `index.php` on the folder `localhost/creative` and after processing the `index.php` using `require_once` extracts all the Html files like header.php from `localhost/creative/themes/` directory. In this whole process if the user enters the wrong URL I am having a problem to redirect him/her to 404 error page located at directory `localhost/creative/themes/404.php`.

In my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /creative/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /creative/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried using `Error Document 404 /themes/404.php` but it is not working. Can anyone tell me how to redirect the user on my website to `404.php` if `url` is wrong? I want the processing to be in `php`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Remove the space in 'Error Document' and try again.

Comment: @HazardousGlitch The above solution did not work instead of redirecting to 404.php it is reopening the index.php with incorrect url.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
Error Document 404 /themes/404.php
```

Use

```
ErrorDocument 404 /themes/404.php
```